# Different size Interface Builder and iPhone Simulator

Tags: xcode, uiview, resize

I have a big problem with Interface Builder.So when I insert into it a `UIView`, when execute iPhone Simulator/Device the `UIView` there isn't.
For showing it i must set, in Interface Builder, a very height size(from 200px), while I set for example 100px I don't see `UIView`.

What is the problem?

To this link there is a screenshot for better understanding about my problem

http://postimg.org/image/tvtu1sduf/

Comment: It is quite hard for anyone to know what the problem is without context, e.g. code. Could you please post it?

Comment: honestly there is no code I just added a view with interface builder

Comment: in essence the size that imposed in interface builder are different from those that I see in the simulator

Comment: in this case i set the height to 50px and in the simulator i don't see it   http://postimg.org/image/4omarvpet/